# The flagging dialogue, from the review queue, seems badly ordered/grouped

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flag-dialog, invalid-flags

While reviewing some flagged answers in the review queue there was one answer that seemed to have an undeserved flag, or flags. So, I pressed the button for the dialogue, up it popped and then I failed to easily identify the 'invalid flags' option for a few moments.

[image]

This, I *think* (dismissing intermittent blindness as an alternative option) is due to the way the list is ordered, and my assumptions that the flagging options would, and *should*, be grouped together (according to their shared purpose), and the 'invalid flags' would be a separate option/group (due to the precisely *inverse* function of that option).

So, I'd request a regrouping of options according to shared functionality (which makes more sense to me, perhaps due to my having recently read "[Don't Make me Think](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758/)"); the following makes more sense to *me*, though I accept it's probably subjective:

- it is spam
- it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- it is not an answer
- it has very low quality
- other (needs ♦ moderator attention)
- it has invalid flags

The blank-line separators are intentional, in order to clearly separate the options from each other; though I'd probably prefer to have boxes or a colour-scheme too to make the grouping obvious.

Note that the purpose of this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) isn't to fix something that's *broken*, simply to *make something easier*.

Comment: I know downvotes don't require explanation, and, anyway, simply represent disagreement here on Meta; but I'm curious about the disagreement here; is it because it's a silly request, or simply too minor/unnecessary? (Obviously it makes sense to me, but contrary opinions would be welcome.)